# Core data fetch relationship count with special limit

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I have a two entities : book, story with one to many relationship. 
And story has property:words.
Now i want to fetch the books whose has story with words more than 1000. How can i get it?

Comment: fetchLimit is an property for NSFetchRequest class. When you setup fetch request you must set fetchLimit what ever you want.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you understand basic Core Data.

try:

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Book"];
fetchRequest.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY stories.words.length MATCHES %@", ".{1000,}"];
```

execute this fetchRequest and see the result.